# SQL query join different tables based on value in a given column?

Tags: sql, database

Well I am designing a domain model and data mapper system for my site. The system has different kind of user domain objects, with the base class for users with child classes for admins, mods and banned users. Every domain object uses data from a table called 'users', while the child classes have an additional table to store admin/mod/banned information. The user type is determined by a column in the table 'users' called 'userlevel', its value is 3 for admins, 2 for mods, 1 for registered users and -1 for banned users.

Now it comes a problem when I work on a members list feature for my site, since the members list is supposed to load all users from the database(with pagination, but lets not worry about this now). The issue is that I want to load the data from both the base user table and additional admin/mod/banned table. As you see, the registered users do not have additional table to store extra data, while for admin/mod/banned users the table is different. Moreover, the columns in these tables are also different.

So How am I supposed to handle this situation using SQL queries? I know I can simply just select from the base user table and then use multiple queries to load additional data if the user level is found to be a given value, but this is a bad idea since it will results in n+1 queries for n admins/mods/banned users, a very expensive trip to database. What else am I supposed to do? Please help.

Comment: Note I've checked similar questions like this one, but mine is quite different since I am loading all data from the tables(SELECT * queries), not just a specific column. This introduces more complexity to my problem, as the number of columns for each row returned can be different. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query all usertypes with one query you will have to have the columns from all tables in your result-table, several of them filled with `null`-values.

To get them filled with data use a left-join like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   userdata u 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN admindata a 
                    ON ( u.userid = a.userid 
                         AND u.usertype = 3 ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN moddata m 
                    ON ( u.userid = m.userid 
                         AND u.usertype = 2 ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN banneddata b 
                    ON ( u.userid = b.userid 
                         AND u.usertype = -1 ) 
WHERE...
```

You could probably drop the `usertype`-condition, since there should only be data in one of the joined tables, but you never know...

Then your program-code will have the job to pick the correct columns based on the `usertype`.

P.S.: Not that `select *` is only for sake of simplicity, in real code better list all of the column-names...

Answer (score 0):

While is totally fine having this hierarchy in your domain classes, I would suggest changing the approach in your database. Otherwise your queries are going to be very complex and slow.

You can have just another table called e.g. users_additional_info with the mix of the columns that you need for all your user types. Then you can do

```
SELECT * FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN users_additional_info ON users.id = users_additional_info.user_id
```

to get all the information in a single simple query. Believe me or not, this approach will save you a lots of headaches in the future when your tables start to grow or you decide to add another type of user.